# How to pass parameters to URL and retrieve with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, instagram-api

I noticed that there are a lot of these questions but I can't find something that relates to my particular project. I am building a Instagram and Google maps app. What I'm trying to do is I'm pulling all JSON format endpoints from Instagram with PHP. With Google maps, I'm adding the longitude and latitude coordinates that this certain API call passes through so you can see where the user has taken the photo at the time it was created. What I'm working on is using [Google's event methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) I am able to center longitude and latitude coordinates to the URL using the function `parent.location.hash`.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){
        var control_center = map.getCenter();
        var lng = control_center.lng();
        var lat = control_center.lat();
        parent.location.hash="&lng="+lng +"&lat="+lat;
        $('.lng').append(lng);
        console.log(map.getCenter());
        console.log(lng +', ' +lat);
      });
```

The issue I'm now running into is when I tried to retrieve lng and lat with PHP `$_GET` it was not working. I found out because it's a fragment and it never gets sent to the server. I found other tips and tricks like `parse_url` but that echos one string. Here is a snippet of what the current URL looks like when someone has done a search and moving Google maps around in the viewport -> `api.php?location=houston#&lng=-95.34908043923292&lat=29.74942788453117`.

The concept behind this API mashup is you have a search box, and you type in Houston, TX. Google maps will load and a feed from Instagram with display that have coordinates that are within Houston, Tx. The map will show where exactly where those photos taken. You move the map and we want more Instagram photos to show up but I can't pass the lng and lat variables to [instagrams api](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search). This is a bit of a long one, sorry.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DUxcd736)

Comment: you may create another PHP-Script(let's call it a proxy) which retrieves the desired data from instagram and request this script via AJAX

Comment: I don't know much about AJAX. But I have looked into it briefly.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this and let me know,

```
$url=parse_url("http://domain.com/api.php?location=houston#&lng=-95.34908043923292&lat=29.74942788453117");

$myurl = $url["fragment"];
 echo $myurl;
```

Update, to get individual variables

```
 $url=parse_url("http://domain.com/api.php?location=houston#&lng=-95.34908043923292&lat=29.74942788453117");

$myurl = $url["fragment"];

echo $myurl.'<br>';

parse_str($myurl);

echo $lng.'<br>';
echo $lat;
```

Comment: did you read this?: *I found out because it's a fragment and it never gets sent to the server*

Comment: but you are able to get the fragment stored in a variable or use it anyway you want using $url["fragment"],

Comment: I have tried that. It creates one long string. I need to be able to get both lat and lng separately.

Comment: @JoseGomez check the updated answer, it works perfectly :)

Comment: @ashish: and how will this variable come from JS to PHP?

Comment: the example expects variables to come from URL but im sure there are simple workarounds to variable coming from JS to php. :)

Comment: @ashish the code seems to work but it's not refreshing. Currently when you move Google maps around the coordinates in the URL update as well but once the page loads new data the fragment is static.

Comment: @JoseGomez in that case, you will need jQuery to do the job, php executed in server and jQuery is executed in client's machine, that means, php will reload the values once the data is sent to server. Since you need the lat and lng to be changed in real time, Im pretty sure jQuery will help you achieve the same thing in simple way. Please consult the refrence below on how to handle URL including fragments, using this you can saperate the lat and lng the way you want.
http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location